# What does this strange sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

They do but flatter themselves.

What is this sentence structure?

Comment: Nothing strange about the sentence or its structure. It's just a difference sense of the word *but*. See the definitions in a good dictionary.

Comment: It's the old-fashioned limiting modifier sense of _but_ (= _just_), and old-fashioned  do-support.

Comment: To see the role of "but", consider these two similar examples: (1) They do nothing but flatter themselves (2) They do little but flatter themselves.

Answer (score 1):

"They do but X" is an old-timey way of saying "they are really only X." In your example, it means they are only saying/doing something to make themselves look good. The 'but' in this case is used as a diminutive like 'just,' 'simply,' 'only,' or 'merely.'

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me read this old style sermon? In the chatroom?

Comment: Sure but I don;t know how.

Comment: go to the chat section and you will see "Text Analysis.